# How do I add a custom image to notify-send?

Tags: notify-send

In notify-send I know that -i can be used to add a stock image to the notification, but how can I add my own custom image? I have gone into usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32 where notify-send pulls from, but it won't show any image at all. Is it possible to include an image other than the stock images?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to tell it where to find the icon, like

```
notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/status/stock_lock-broken.png  summary test
```

And of course you can use your own icon too, not only the default ones.

For using an icon from your own home directory you would use one of

```
notify-send -i ~/pictures/picture-name.png summary test
notify-send -i /home/<yourusername>/pictures/picture-name.png summary test
```

Remember: names are case sensitive and paths must be absolute paths. `/Home` probably doesn't exist on your system.

`man notify-send` will tell you about other options too.

Comment: Thank you for this. I must have been messing up the path somewhere. I know that it's best to store these icons on the file system, but if I had my icons stored in home/pictures, would the code be 
`notify-send -i /Home/Pictures/picture-name.png  summary test`

Comment: @Lmuller18: Not quite - see my updated answer please.

Comment: @guntbert The `.../256x256/...` sub-directory had better icons for me than the `.../32x32/...` sub-directory. Thanks for sharing location.

Comment: I'll just add that there's a ton of icons in `/usr/share` in many scattered directories. To find which icon I want to use for my project, I installed shotwell (`apt-get install shotwell`), which is an image viewer that allows you to scan directories recursively. Anyone looking to find icons for `notify-send` may also want to checkout the following software https://askubuntu.com/questions/147334/show-all-pictures-recursively-include-any-subfolders

Comment: Absolute pathnames - how intuitive. That should be worth an update in the manpage.