# I want shotwell to open all .cr2 files in a folder and all its subfolders, what command line do I use?

Tags: command-line, shotwell

Something like

```
shotwell *.cr2 ./
```

That doesn't work, but basically I want to use shotwell to open all files that end with `.cr2` and in the current directory (including subfolders)

The context is that I am missing photos that I took on my camera that I have since deleted off of my memory card.

There are thumbnails for them in shotwell's "missing images" but I can't find them.  So I figured I'd run `photorec` to try and find them.  As a result photorec gave me a boat load of folders and files, enough that it filled up my hard drive.  Instead of sifting through all the files one by one, I decided to search for .cr2 files on my hard drive, while avoiding a particular folder called `Photogs` that I know doesn't have them because those weren't part of the `photorec` data dump.

Comment: @EliahKagan see comments (which continued into chat!) for detail [here](//askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1341892). I am not sure whether and how to edit the question, so please advise, given that you created such a beautiful answer

Comment: @user285884 The most recent edits to my answer include a detailed procedure for building a tree of symbolic links to just .cr2 files, which can then be opened in Shotwell (and some other methods). This should overcome the problem of seeing extra, non-.cr2 files in Shotwell as well as the problem of not having enough space on the destination device to move or copy the files. I wasn't sure, from the [relevant chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51091/discussion-between-zanna-and-user285884), if you've solved this yet.

Answer (score 7):

Usually, you will want to just open Shotwell and drag in the folder.

If you need to, you can make the shell build a list of CR2 files and tell Shotwell to open just those files. Occasionally that may be what you want, but in this case [that did not do quite what you needed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/51091/2017/1/2) due to Shotwell's behavior -- in some other circumstances, a feature -- of automatically showing you other image files (of all types) residing in the same folders as the images you opened.

To ensure Shotwell only knows about the images you are interested in, you could clone the directory tree somewhere else, copying only `.cr2` files and the folders that contain them, but nothing else. That may take up substantial additional space, though. So another approach is to construct a hierarchy of [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) -- where instead of having having a new directory tree of *copies of* your original `.cr2` files, you have a new directory tree of *syminks to* them. This takes up far less space.

This answer covers all those approaches.

## Opening a Folder of Images (Including Subfolders) in Shotwell

Shotwell itself gives you two ways to open a whole directory tree of photos. If these will work for you, then you won't need to do anything clever in the command line or even use it at all. If not, you might end up doing this in connection with another technique.  (For example, if you end up creating a new directory of symlinks or copies of your `.cr2` files, you can use one of these ways to open it.)

### Way 1: Just open the whole folder in Shotwell.

In Shotwell, in the *File* menu, click *Import from Folder*. Then select the folder you want to import images from. This won't be limited to `.cr2` files, but if you're opening files from multiple subfolders containing `.cr2` images created from a digital camera, then most likely those will be the only files present.

[image: Screenshot of the Import from Folder menu item in the File menu of Shotwell.]

See [Jakob's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/147337/22949) to [Show all pictures recursively (include any subfolders)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147334/show-all-pictures-recursively-include-any-subfolders) for more information.

### Way 2: Drag the folder into Shotwell.

With most desktop environments and file browsers, you can also open Shotwell and drag the folder that contains your images into the Shotwell window. Like *Import from Folder*, this is another way Shotwell recommends to open photos.

[image: Screenshot of me dragging my Desktop folder into Shotwell to import the images it contains.]

When you drag from a file browser window or your desktop into Shotwell, you can drag to a specific library. Or if you don't have multiple libraries set up, you can just drag basically anywhere and it works. (You don't even have to drag into the left pane.)

This method is very convenient, and it is as powerful as manually selecting the folder (with *File* > *Import from Folder*, as described above). When you open files or folders using **either of these methods**, Shotwell gives you the option to open the photos without copying them into its library.

[image: Screenshot of the dialog box in Shotwell that asks the user to choose between copying images to the location of their Shotwell library, or importing them in place, without any copying.]

To import without copying, click *Import in Place* instead of *Copy Photos*.

---

## Launching Shotwell with a List of Image Filenames

If for some reason you want or need to do this by running a command in the Terminal, you can run the `shotwell` command and pass each image's filename to it as an argument. [Globstar](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) makes it easy:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
shotwell **/*.cr2
```

That opens the `.cr2` files located anywhere in the current directory. It differs from running Shotwell and then dragging the folder in, in that Shotwell will only try to import the the files whose names you give it. However, since Shotwell often shows other image files from the same folders as the files you've told it to open, this may not be adequate for your needs. (And [further information you've given about your problem suggests that it is not](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/51091/2017/1/2). See below for an alternative.)

This **does not include files or subfolders whose names start with `.`**. However, if you have CR2 files whose names start with a dot, then most of the time you probably *don't* want to open them in Shotwell anyway. Unless you've deliberately named your files or folders in this way, a dotfile with an image or document filename extension is more likely to be a metadata file rather than an actual image or document. For example, [macOS often adds such files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them) (e.g., `._kittens.cr2` for an actual picture `kittens.cr2`) when accessing external media (including flash drives and digital cameras).

If you do want **to also find files whose names start with `.` or that are in folders whose names start with `.`**, then enable dotglob as well. You can do this with `shopt -s dotglob` or by passing both `globstar` and `dotglob` to the `shopt` builtin:

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob
```

By default, globs are case-sensitive. But you might want **to match filenames case-insensitively**, so as to open files ending in `.cr2`, `.Cr2`, `.cR2`, and `.CR2`. To do that, either:

- Enable nocaseglob by running `shopt -s` with `nocaseglob`, either by itself or with other shell options. For example, to run `shotwell` on all `.cr2` files, searching case-insensitively and including `.`-files and files in `.`-directories:

  ```
  shopt -s globstar dotglob nocaseglob
  shotwell **/*.cr2
  ```
- *Or*, use `.[cC][rR]2` instead of `.cr2` in your glob pattern itself. For example, this accomplishes the same as above:

  ```
  shopt -s globstar dotglob
  shotwell **/*.[cC][rR]2
  ```

  Note that case sensitivity is entirely separate from whether or not `.` files and folders are matched. You can remove `dotglob` from the examples above and they can still be case-insensitive.

**To specify a directory** rather than just using the current directory, put its name and a `/` before the `**/*.cr2` glob. For example, replacing the `shotwell` command above with this one will open all the `.cr2` files inside the `Pictures` subdirectory of your home directory:

```
shotwell ~/Pictures/**/*.cr2
```

Unlike with the first command that uses your current directory, no matter where you run that command you will be telling Shotwell to open the same files.

#### Testing

If you really have to use the terminal for this, then I'm guessing it may be part of something more complex. If you like, you can test such commands before actually running them by replacing `shotwell` with `printf '%s\n'`. Instead of passing the filenames to Shotwell, that lists them one per line. For example, on my machine:

```
ek@Io:~$ printf '%s\n' ~/tmp/**/*.cr2
/home/ek/tmp/another image.cr2
/home/ek/tmp/image.cr2
/home/ek/tmp/some folder/image3.cr2
```

#### Turning Off Globstar and Other Shell Options

The globstar shell option has be enabled to work, which is what the `shopt -s globstar` command (above) did. If it's already enabled, then you don't need multiple commands. And you only need to set globstar once per shell instance.

You can turn globstar back off by running:

```
shopt -u globstar
```

And you can *check* whether globstar is on or off by running:

```
shopt globstar
```

If you're using globstar in a script, you should consider turning it back off if there might be code that comes afterwards in the same script that is not written with globstar in mind. For example, writing `**` when you mean `*` is usually no problem when globstar is disabled, but with globstar turned on, it can cause serious problems by making a command affect far more files than someone intended.

Similarly, if you used dotglob or nocaseglob and you want too turn them off, you can do so with `shopt -u dotglob` and `shopt -u nocaseglob`, respectively. You can also pass multiple shell options to `shopt -u` to unset them at the same time. For example, to turn off `globstar,` `dotglob`, and `nocaseglob`:

```
shopt -u globstar dotglob nocaseglob
```

Compared to globstar, there are fewer serious mistakes you might make because you forgot you left dotglob or nocaseglob on. But other people (including people you consult on sites like Ask Ubuntu) usually assume dotglob and nocaseglob are disabled when they suggest commands for you to use, unless you tell them otherwise.

**For more information on these glob-related shell options** (and also on [globs in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))), see the [bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/). They are all covered primarily in [4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin). For globstar, see also [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching). For dotglob, see also [3.5.8 Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion).

---

## Building a New Directory Tree

Since in your case [you seem to really need Shotwell to show *only* `.cr2` files, you have non-`.cr2` files in the same folders with `.cr2` files, and image browsing in Shotwell is automatically offering those files too](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/51091/2017/1/2), it looks like you will need to have a folder that contains no other image files than the `.cr2` files you're trying to open.

[Moving the files, as you've suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34509441#34509441), is one approach, but I recommend instead either *copying* the files or, better, *making [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the files* (see also [FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/symlink)), because:

- If you're moving the files across devices, that requires copying anyway, so in that case moving is no faster.
- If you have the space, it's often a good idea to keep an unmodified folder of everything you started with until you're satisfied that what you've done is correct according to your needs. Obviously this is not always applicable or practical. But in your case, these files are the result of a data recovery operation. It may be useful to keep an easily perused record of precisely what was recovered and from where.
- If you choose to create symbolic links, **the amount of additional space consumed is extremely small**. (If the target disk is *completely full*, though, then you will still need to free up space on it -- or use a different target disk -- to create symlinks.)

There is another decision for you to make, too. Do you create all the new entries (whether they be copies or symlinks) in the same directory, *flattening* the file hierarchy? Or do you create directories at the destination corresponding to each of the directories at the source that contain at least one `.cr2` file?

- Flattening the file hierarchy lets you see all the files at once, easily. In particular, it is easy to see the files' names and sizes all at once, as well as to select any combination of the files in a graphical file browser.
- But it also loses information about what folders they were in, which may be valuable (though you can return to the original folder and look for them there if you don't move the files).
- The bigger problem with flattening the file hierarchy, though, is what happens if you have **two or more files of the same name in different places**. If you flatten the file hierarchy, then depending on how you do it, either all but the first will fail to be copied (or linked) and you'll get an error or warning, or all but the last copy (or link) will be *overwritten*.

  This is another reason I recommend copying or making symlinks rather than moving files. If you "successfully" move multiple files into the same file, you've lost all but the last one!

Because of the disadvantages of flattening everything into a single directory without subdirectories, the approaches I take here *build a new directory tree* at the destination.

### Way 1: Copying

*I show this first because it's a little simpler, but I suggest you instead create symbolic links ("Way 2"), especially if the destination drive might not have enough space to hold all the files. "Way 2," which is a bit more complicated, is much more detailed because there seem to be fewer resources on how to use that technique, it's the way I expect most people in this situation will prefer, and information that applies to both methods -- basic advice about escaping spaces in paths -- is given there rather than here.*

When you need to copy a directory tree and you need to customize the copy operation, you should usually use [`rsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rsync.1.html) instead of [`cp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/cp.1.html). This is one of those cases.

Replacing `src` with the path to the top-level directory containing all your CR2 files, and replacing `dest` with the name of the directory you want to create that will contain a hierarchy of symbolic links to the CR2 files, run:

```bash
rsync -rl --prune-empty-dirs --include='*/' --include='*.cr2' --exclude='*' src/ dest
```

Don't forget the `/` after the name of the source directory, [unless you want an additional top-level directory to be created inside *`dest`*](http://qdosmsq.dunbar-it.co.uk/blog/2013/02/rsync-to-slash-or-not-to-slash/). That is, if you omit the trailing `/`, then `rsync` will make the destination directory for you, inside *`dest`*. For example, suppose *`src`* is a relative path containing no `/`. Then:

- With `src/` in your `rsync` command, you get a symlink `dest/foo/bar.cr2` for the file `src/foo/bar.cr2`.
- With *`src`* in your `rsync` command, you get a symlink `dest/src/foo/bar.cr2` for the file `src/foo/bar.cr2`.

Since it could be confusing for the top-level directory where symlinks will be placed to have the same name as that of the top-level directory containing the `.cr2` files that the symlinks will point to, I recommend you include the `/` at the end of the destination directory name in your `rsync` command. (And, for the source directory, give it a directory that is empty, doesn't exist, or is otherwise dedicated to this purpose. Otherwise, you'll be cluttering up some other folder.)

As is generally the case when you pass the name of a file or directory to a command-line program or script, if your destination or source directory paths contain any blank spaces (or characters treated specially by the shell, like `\`, `$`, `'`, and various other punctuation), **then you will have to quote them**. I've detailed how to do this, for the most common case of spaces, in "Way 2"--the advice about quoting in that section applies here as well. However, if you're not sure how to quote the name of a folder, you can have Ubuntu do it for you by simply dragging the folder into the Temrminal; *its full path will be pasted in with correct quotation*.

After copying just the `.cr2` files and the folders that contain them, you can open the destination folder up in Shotwell. (See *"Opening a Folder of Images (Including Subfolders) in Shotwell"* above.) However, before running `rsync`, I recommend you decide if want to skip entries that start with `.` and if you want to include entries with case-variant suffixes. If so, you'll have to run some slightly different `rsync` command.

#### Customizing the Handling of Dotted Entries and Case Sensitivity

You may want to use a different `rsync` command to change whether or not files and directories that start with a dot are skipped and whether or not you want case-sensitivity in matching the suffix `.cr2`.

**The command above *does* include directories and files whose names start with `.`.** To exclude such files and directories, put `--exclude='.*/' --exclude='.*'` before all other `--include`s  and `--exclude`s. That is, use this `rsync` command instead (with the appropriate substitutions for *`src`* and *`dest`*, of course):

```bash
rsync -rl --prune-empty-dirs --exclude='.*/' --exclude='.*' --include='*/' --include='*.cr2' --exclude='*' src/ dest
```

**The `rsync` commands shown thus far have been case-sensitive** and will not copy files that end in `.CR2`, `.Cr2`, or `.cR2` rather than `.cr2`. If you want such files to be copied, then you'll need to account for that by using the `--include` pattern `*.[cC][rR]2` in place of `*.cr2`.

This third command is *case-insensitive* and (like the first command) does *not* skip files and directories whose names start with `.`:

```bash
rsync -rl --prune-empty-dirs --include='*/' --include='*.[cC][rR]2' --exclude='*' src/ dest
```

If you take the approach of copying files with `rsync`, and you're not sure which of these commands you want, **I suggest using that one** if you want to make sure not to miss anything. However, you should be aware that dotfiles may contain metadata, and dotfiles named like images may not really be images. See the discussions on dotfiles in the *"Launching Shotwell with a List of Image Filenames"* section above, and on dotfiles and case sensitivity in "Way 2" below.

This fourth command is *case-insensitive* and (like the second command) *does* skip files and directories whose names start with `.`:

```bash
rsync -rl --prune-empty-dirs --exclude='.*/' --exclude='.*' --include='*/' --include='*.[cC][rR]2' --exclude='*' src/ dest
```

### Way 2: Creating Symbolic Links

*This is what I recommend you do, though Way 1 is okay if you have enough space on the destination drive. You don't have to read Way 1 to use this.*

The method presented here makes a list of `.cr2` files and loops through the list, creating target directories as needed and populating them with symbolic links to each `.cr2` file.

This is just complicated enough that I suggest putting it in a script rather than just typing it in interactively. You can put the script wherever you like, but for convenience, I'll show how to do it with the script placed directly in your home folder.

#### Write (or paste in) the script.

Create a text file, **`make-symlinks`**, in your home folder. No file extension is needed.

You can do this with any text editor, like Vim, Nano, Gedit, or Leafpad. Don't use a word processor like LibreOffice Writer, though. (You could even do it by running `cat > ~/make-symlinks`, pasting in the contents of the file, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on a new line, if you wanted.)

If you name the script something other than `make-symlinks`, make sure to use that name when you run commands that use the script later.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar dotglob nocaseglob

for f in **/*.cr2; do
    mkdir -p "$1/$(dirname "$f")"
    ln -s "$PWD/$f" "$1/$f"
done
```

Put that in the file, and save the file. This script uses globstar, a Bash feature explained above in *"Launching Shotwell with a List of Image Filenames"*.

#### You can change how it handles dotted entries and case sensitivity.

Depending on your needs, you may want to make some changes:

- If you don't want to include `.cr2` files whose names start with `.` or that reside in directories whose names start with `.`, remove `dotglob` from the `shopt` line.

  Files and directories whose name start with `.` are often used for metadata (see the *"Launching Shotwell with a List of Image Filenames"* section above). On the other hand, if you want to make sure you have everything, or if there's something inexplicably missing that you are pretty sure is there, then should keep `dotglob`.
- If you want to include only files that end in exactly `.cr2` but *not* case variants (`.CR2`, `.Cr2`, and `.cR2`), then you should remove `nocaseglob`. Since your situation involves data recovery and *Shotwell will not show you any of the files you missed* when you open up the directory of symbolic links -- that's the point of this method, after all -- you will likely want to keep `nocaseglob`.

#### Make it executable.

Run this command to mark your script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/make-symlinks
```

#### Run it at the source and pass the destination as an argument.

Then change directory to the source directory, i.e., the top-level folder that contains the pictures. For example, if they are in the `Pictures` subdirectory of your home directory, you would run:

```
cd ~/Pictures
```

This is where you'll run the script. Pass the destination directory to the script as a command-line argument.

For example, if you want a directory called `cr2s` to be created on your Desktop to contain the symbolic links, run:

```
~/make-symlinks ~/Desktop/cr2s
```

Or if you just want that directory directly in your home folder:

```
~/make-symlinks ~/cr2s
```

Or if you have a drive mounted at `/media/you/MyDrive` and you want to create a folder on it called `links` to contain the symbolic links:

```
~/make-symlinks /media/you/MyDrive/links
```

But if the drive is `/media/you/My Drive` (with a space) then you must use quotation. Any of these works (use just one, don't run them all):

```
~/make-symlinks '/media/you/My Drive/links'
~/make-symlinks /media/you/'My Drive'/links
~/make-symlinks /media/you/My\ Drive/links
```

But if you use `~` for your home directory, don't quote that:

```
~/make-symlinks ~/'Two Words'   # good
~/make-symlinks ~/Two\ Words    # good
~/make-symlinks '~/Two Words'   # BAD, because ~ doesn't get expanded
```

`make-symlinks` creates the destination directory for you if it doesn't already exist, just as it creates subdirectories within it. However, it still works if the destination already exists.

You can even run it multiple times and pass the same destination directory (for example, if you interrupted it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), though you'll get `failed to create symbolic link` errors for the symlinks that already exist, and that could be confusing.

You probably don't want to pass the name of a directory that already exists and contains unrelated files (like your home directory) to `make-symlinks`. If you do, you can expect a whole bunch of symlinks and subfolders to be created in it. You probably want to use a new directory -- or one that doesn't exist yet -- for `make-symlinks`.

#### Import the newly created symlink tree into Shotwell.

After you run `make-symlinks`, just import the directory you passed to it into Shotwell, using either of the methods given in the first part of this answer (*"Opening a Folder of Images (Including Subfolders) in Shotwell"*). For example, you could open Shotwell and drag the folder in.

Since all the the entries in folder are either symbolic links to `.cr2` files or directories that contain them, with no other file types, Shotwell should not see any of the other files.

Answer (score 5):

Shotwell will cycle through all the images found in every directory where an image is open, so using `find -name '*.cr2' -exec shotwell '{}' +` as I orginally suggested does not really help. Since Shotwell's settings are rather limited, the only way I can think of to open only the files you want is to move the files to a new directory by themselves.

You can use `find` for that:

```
mkdir ~/cr2files
find -type f -iname '*.cr2' -not -path './dir/*' -exec cp -v -- '{}' ~/cr2files \;
```

Replace `cp` with `mv` if you want to avoid creating duplicate files.

#### Notes:

- `mkdir ~/cr2files` make a new directory in your home directory
- `find` search recursively from the current directory downwards through the tree
- `-type f` search only for files
- `-iname` search for files by name, ignoring case
- `'*.cr2'` names ending with `.cr2` - use quotes to stop the shell expanding the glob before it's passed to `find`
- `-not -path './dir/*'` will exclude the contents of directory `dir` from the results
- `{}` represents the paths of the found files
- `--` after `cp` is to tell `cp` not to accept any further options, which avoids any filenames beginning with `-` causing issues

You can then open any file in the new directory with Shotwell and cycle through them all

Comment: why does this also open .jpg and .png files in the directory?  I see that it specifies *.cr2?  How do I get it to just look at .cr2 files when I push the left arrow on shotwell?   If I use a \ instead of a +, nothing happens :(

Comment: oh! this is a problem @user285884 I'm sorry, shotwell cycles through all the images it finds in the directory... let me see if I can figure out a way around it...

Comment: @user285884 edited, but I can't work out an elegant solution :(

Comment: ok, thanks for the effort!  what about this, I search through the directory for .cr2 files and move them into a separate folder call cr2files.  I've done it within one subfolder by using mv *.cr2 ../cr2files/ and it worked!.  However, how do I do this and specify which files to look into?  Something like "hey linux look at folders 1-10 for .cr2 files and move it into the cr2files folder"?  Thanks Zanna

Comment: @user285884 I recommend using `find` for that job - I just edited my command a little bit, but you need to correct the path for your `cr2files` directory if it's not in the top level of your home directory. For example if the path is `/home/username/photos/cr2files` then the command would have `~/photos/cr2files`. Does this help or am I missing the point?

Comment: well for some context on where I am.  I lost a few pictures.  So I did a photorec and it gave me a boatload of folders, enough to fill up my entire hard drive.  So I want to look in all the folders in my hard drive except for one because that one has a ton of .cr2 files that I know are not the one I'm looking for.  So I want linux to go through all of the folders except for one.  I'm not sure your code does that.  What does {} do?  Also the "--" after the -v?  Thanks Zanna!

Comment: ah @user285884 please see my edit - you can easily exclude a directory from `find`

Comment: For some reason it doesn't do anything I just get ">" and a cursor.   Perhaps there are so many files to go through?  but doesn't -v mean it will tell me what it is doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51091/discussion-between-zanna-and-user285884).

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 - Using `xargs` when file names contain spaces

As comments below have pointed out, using `back ticks` (Option 3 below) will break when file names contain spaces. The safer method of using `find` command and passing output to `shotwell` using the `xargs` option looks like this:

```
find . -name "*.cr2" -print0 | xargs -0 shotwell
```

The `-print0` flag tells find to use `\0` (null character) delimiters between filenames, and the `-0` flag tells `xargs` to expect these `\0` delimiters.

Credit to the excellent answers found here ([How to pipe list of files returned by find command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864316/how-to-pipe-list-of-files-returned-by-find-command-to-cat-to-view-all-the-files)) on Stack Overflow.

### Option 2 - Using `-exec` when file names contain spaces

As a comment below points out, the `-exec` option also supports file names containing spaces. Other comments below point out this breaks when number of files exceeds This would look like this:

```
find . -name "*.cr2" -exec shotwell {} +
```

### Option 3 - When file names don't have spaces

In the old days, before file names had spaces and became 256 characters long this option worked fine. You'll find this option mentioned on many other websites but **you should not use this option**. Back in the day, using the `find` command and passing output to `shotwell` was the simplest method:

```
shotwell `find . -name "*.cr2"`
```

This starts the `find` from the current directory and includes all sub-directories:

- Note the use of <kbd>back tick</kbd> and not single quotes <kbd>'</kbd> above. Using back-ticks is similar to enclosing phrase in `$(...)` within bash.
- The first argument `.` gives `find` a starting point which is the current directory. You could pass `/home/$USER/Pictures` or something else instead of `.`.
- The second argument `-name` tells find to search for file names (not directories).
- This technique works for all commands, not just `shotwell`. ie You can use it for `cat`, `head`, `tail` and most other popular Linux commands.

Comment: Using the backticks is sort of frowned upon, plus it has issues with word splitting. I'd recommend you change it to pipe with `xargs`  and use `-0` all filenames use NULL string as separator

Comment: [The problem with the approach in this answer is that it does the wrong thing when any of the filenames, or any names of directories that contain the files, have spaces.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23729069/) Note that, although many people prefer the `$(` `)` command substitution syntax to the backtick command substitution syntax, that's not relevant to this problem -- they both fail in exactly the same way. @Serg I suggest posting a new answer about how to do it with `xargs`. (Putting the substitution in `"` `"` also wouldn't work: all the `find` results would be passed as a single argument.)

Comment: I also saw `xargs` option on `Stack Overflow` when writing this answer. I'll expand with that option too. Unfortunately I had to boot with Windows 8 this morning to fix corrupted `NTFS` partition so testing was problematic. I'll update the answer later though. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: why not just use `-exec`?

Comment: @Zanna I'll add the `-exec` option too :)

Comment: @Zanna Good idea--I recommend posting an answer. `-exec` with `;` might not do the right thing--it'll run `shotwell` once for reach file found. But I think `-exec` with `+` should work well. A `+`-terminated `-exec` will run the command multiple times if `find` finds more results than the maximum number of arguments supported by the system, so with thousands of photos (and *if* shotwell doesn't support being run additional times to open new files in an existing instance) it may not work right. But that would break any other method that involves building a single command from the results, too.

Comment: @Zanna I'm leaning towards moving Option 1 to the bottom and pointing out although it's a common answer on other websites explaining why it's a bad idea to use it in modern times. Would that make sense?

Comment: @Zanna `-exec`  won't work if the number of files is above number of maximum command-line arguments allowed by the system ( had that in my experience . Surely most people don't have that many files, but you never know.  But for a batch of files in range of hundreds it's alright too.

Comment: up to you if you want to do that... I would definitely warn against using it if you post it at all

Comment: I put in bold not to use the option. Because the option appears frequently on other websites I thought it was important to include it and point out not to use it. After all I found into the easy solution trap, and I'm sure others will in the future too.

Comment: @Serg the maximum number of arguments is 2.6 million according to this Stack Overflow Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185017/maximum-number-of-bash-arguments-max-num-cp-arguments

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's actually more complicated than that. See this:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/85039 That's first of all, and second , 2.6 million of files, when you're doing it with `find` is a very realistic number, which is possible to overcome.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix also, if you read the answers there, it's not 2.6 million files actually - it's size of arguments buffer (apparently in kilobytes, although don't quite me on that ), which means that with long filenames  that buffer will be filled up really really fast.

Comment: @Serg certainly there is a lot of reading when it comes to max arguments. It's starting to give me a headache :(. I think one fellow said it best in that bash will slow to a crawl long before 2.6 million or much more below that is reached.

Answer (score -2):

I wasn't aware shotwell even opened raw files. I am certain you might get more mileage with digikam or darktable. Digikam comes with some Kde components and is a pretty good photo manager. Darktable comes with very good non-destructive editing capabilities.

Comment: Can you expand this answer (by [edit]ing) to include detailed information on how to use Digikam (or Darktable) to browse through just `.cr2` files in a folder? If so, then this could be valuable, since the original poster has had trouble getting Shotwell to show *just* the `.cr2` files. Although I've added additional approaches to [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/867198/22949) to make it possible to use Shotwell to browse just those files and no others, I rather strongly suspect Shotwell isn't the best tool for this.